# Monit stops responding when more that 512 configurations are added

Tags: ruby-on-rails, monit

Should be a fairly simple question but is anyone aware of any limitations regarding monit and having more than 512 configurations and if so any way to bypass?

It seems to stop being able to load items when it hits the 512 limit but we are unable to find any mentions of this in documentations or elsewhere.

The version of monit we are using is not the latest so if upgrading will solve it thats also fine but would just need to know if thats the issue or not before doing the upgrade?

If i have missed anything just let me know and ill speak to the gent that handles this stuff our end (thats not me if you couldnt tell by my vagueness).

Cheers in advance for any help guys, much appreciated

Regards

Scott.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a hard coded limit today.

> Should be a fairly simple question but is anyone aware of any
> limitations regarding monit and having more than 512 configurations
> and if so any way to bypass?

You are right, the limit is not documented.

With regards,
Lutz

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hey @lutzmad, thanks for the info, it's good to know about the limit but are you aware of any bypass or a way to increase the limit?
Regards,
Scott

Comment: Sorry, the limit is still hard coded and increased to 1024 now. You will find this limit in the documentation, see https://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html#INCLUDE-FILES for additional information.